# Snowflake:Tuning:Why does it aggregates thrice

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Why does Snowflake do aggregation thrice?
As below screenshot  Aggregate[3] is doing 3 MAX/SUM  and Aggregate[4] does 2 MAX/SUM , Aggregate[7] does the single MAX/SUM

Is there a way to avoid it

**Aggregate[3]**

```
MAX(MAX(MAX(D.TYPEID)))
MAX(MAX(MAX(D.CTRY)))
SUM(SUM(SUM(D.AMOUNT)))
MAX(MAX(MAX(D.MAX_DATE)
```

**Aggregate[4]**

```
MAX(MAX(D.TYPEID))
MAX(MAX(D.CTRY)))
SUM(SUM(D.AMOUNT))
MAX(MAX(D.MAX_DATE)
```

**Aggregate[7]**

```
MAX(D.TYPEID)
MAX(D.CTRY)
SUM(D.AMOUNT)
MAX(D.MAX_DATE)



CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE ABC AS
          SELECT
              TO_CHAR(d.date,\'YYYYMMDD\')::number(38,0) AS dateid,
              d.date                     AS date,
              d.id                       AS id,
              MAX(typeid)         AS typeid,
              MAX(cntry)                   AS cntry,
              SUM(amount)                 AS amount,
              object_construct(...),
              ....,
              ....,
              MAX(max_date) AS max_date
          FROM table_a d
          JOIN table_b s ON s.id = d.id
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a "smart" distributed process in action.

For example, in a simpler query:

```sql
select max(a.l_orderkey), max(b.l_quantity)
from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf10.lineitem a
cross join snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf10.lineitem b
limit 10;
```

Doing a cross join of a table with 60M rows with itself would need to process 3.6 quadrillion rows - but Snowflake is smarter than that.

As we are asking for `max()` on both sides, it's able to reduce the 15m rows to 4.15k rows on one side and 15m rows on the other. That's "only" 62 billion rows to process after doing the cross join.

But still, we need to reduce those 62 billion rows to only one. Instead of doing this in a single thread, multiple threads will process the generated 62 billion rows. That's the second aggregate.

This will happen until we get a result.

[image]

So to answer your question: Snowflake is doing optimizations on a distributed way, to optimize the results of your query that's joining 11.8 billion rows with 12.8 billion rows - by reducing the rows that could produce the aggregate requested.